# Find unique permutations of a set with constraints on sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, graph-theory, combinatorial-designs

I have a set of 11 items {A, B, ... J, K}. I would like to find 11 permutations so that:

1. Each permutation starts with a different item (e.g. the first with A, second with B...)
2. Each sequence of two items in the 11 permutations is unique (if the sequence AB appears in the first permutation, it must not appear in any of the other 10 permutations).

I would think this also means each permutation should end with a different item.

For instance, these two permutations are a start:

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K
B,D,F,H,J,A,C,E,G,K,I
```

How could I find a solution?

Comment: This seems to be a graph theory problem to me. Take the complete directed graph on $\{1, \ldots, n\}$. You want to find $n$ disjoint directed Hamiltonian paths, each starting at a different vertex. Each edge will be used exactly once. I was able to do it by hand when $n=4$ (ABCD, BDAC, CADB, DCBA), so it's plausible that it can be done. I've added the graph-theory tag; hopefully somebody with expertise will be able to chime in and just point you to a solution.

Comment: I discussed a related problem [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4000891/177399). If you add the additional constraint that, when the permutations are put in the rows of a $11\times11$ square, the columns must be permutations as well, then this is an open problem but suspected to be impossible. Namely, the $n\times n$ version of the harder variant is suspected to be impossible whenever $n$ is an odd prime, which has been confirmed for $n=3,5,7$. I have confirmed your version is impossible for $n=3$ as well.